# Pandas Read_Parquet NaN error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parquet

I need help in handling the **NaN** error I am getting in reading a parquet file in Python3.
There is a column returning "**NaN**" while I try to read the file.
Per requirement, I cannot change the content of this file - So I cannot go in and handle the offending column.

Here is the code I am using to read the file:

```
df = pd.read_parquet("parquet_file.parquet")
```

Here is the error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Having come across a similar issue, I found the solution (in my case) was to pip install pyarrow.
The documentation for `read_parquet` mentions the `engine` argument. `auto` is default, using the fastparquet library if pyarrow is not available.

pip installing pyarrow then rerunning the code seems to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

pandas.read_parquet(parquet_file.parquet, columns=[column1,column2])

You can specify the list of columns you want to process from the file exluding the column which is having issue

Comment: I dont have access to the content of the file. So I dont have a list of columns.